# Why are Django related object queries not cached?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following unit test:

```
def test_cache(self):
    with self.assertNumQueries(1):
        print(database.records.all())
        print(database.records.all())
        print(database.records.all())
```

The test fails because 3 queries are made:

```
Captured queries were:
1. SELECT "store_record"."id", "store_record"."key", "store_record"."database_id", "store_record"."user_id", "store_record"."organization_id", "store_record"."data", "store_record"."created_at", "store_record"."updated_at" FROM "store_record" WHERE "store_record"."database_id" = '7d86d143-9e4e-4420-801c-3d3c5e6875fb'::uuid LIMIT 21
2. SELECT "store_record"."id", "store_record"."key", "store_record"."database_id", "store_record"."user_id", "store_record"."organization_id", "store_record"."data", "store_record"."created_at", "store_record"."updated_at" FROM "store_record" WHERE "store_record"."database_id" = '7d86d143-9e4e-4420-801c-3d3c5e6875fb'::uuid LIMIT 21
3. SELECT "store_record"."id", "store_record"."key", "store_record"."database_id", "store_record"."user_id", "store_record"."organization_id", "store_record"."data", "store_record"."created_at", "store_record"."updated_at" FROM "store_record" WHERE "store_record"."database_id" = '7d86d143-9e4e-4420-801c-3d3c5e6875fb'::uuid LIMIT 21
```

Why is the records field not cached? What is telling Django to do refetch the data from the database?

Comment: why would they cache? did you implement caching?

Comment: The cache does *not* work that way. Django's querysets have caching so the *same* `QuerySet` *object* will not make a second call. But constructing two different querysets will not reuse each othe. That would probably result in unwanted consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/#un) :

> As well as caching of the whole QuerySet, there is caching of the
> result of attributes on ORM objects. In general, attributes that are
> not callable will be cached. For example, assuming the example blog
> models:
>
> ```
>  entry = Entry.objects.get(id=1)
>  entry.blog  # Blog object is retrieved at this point
>  entry.blog  # cached version, no DB access   But in general, callable attributes cause DB lookups every time:
>
>  entry = Entry.objects.get(id=1)
>  entry.authors.all()  # query performed
>  entry.authors.all()  # query performed again
> ```

But this is not problem as if you need to access authors ( store_records in your case) you would properly use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related)